# Subtitle and VideoView with URI (Streaming video)

Tags: android, android-videoview, subtitle

I use a **VideoView** with **Uri** (so this video is streaming).

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mUrl));
```

I add **subtitle** in this VideoView in the `OnPreparedListener` like this:

```
mediaPlayer.addTimedTextSource(mSrtPath, MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
mediaPlayer.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
mediaPlayer.setOnTimedTextListener((mp, text) -> {
    if (text != null) {
        handler.post(() -> mTextSubtitle.setText(text.getText()));
    }
});
```

> Everything works perfectly.

I use a **SeekBar** to move forward or backward in the video with `mVideoView.seekTo(newPosition);`.

> Except that when I go back in the video and I restart, I have no
>   callback in `setOnTimedTextListener` for subtitles to where I back in
>   the video. Would anyone have a solution?

I hope my problem is clear. If you need more information, feel free to ask me in the comments.

Comment: Hi Mikhael, I'm having a very similar issue. The subtitles are not working (onTimedText is never called) using a data source (onPrepareAsync is executed). But if I create the media player with the local file (without using the setDataSouce method - no need to call onPrepare), the onTimedText callback is being executed successfully.  

Have you solved this issue? can you share your code? thanks in advance!